# IAM Cannot access my account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

As a new user I have been logging in for a couple of weeks now using my amazon login details. Yesterday I set myself up with a IAM user identity with administrator rights. After that I find I can no longer access my account. So for example trying to access Billing returns "You are currently signed in as an IAM user that does not have permissions to the requested page."

Biggest problem is the IAM login page appears to have hijacked the old login page where I could use my amazon credentials...

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation...

**"If you want to sign in to the console using your AWS root account credentials instead of IAM user credentials, go to the account sign-in page and then click Sign in using root account credentials. The Amazon Web Services sign-in page appears that you can use to sign in with your AWS root account credentials."**

If the link is missing make sure javascript is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant documentation:

[The IAM Console and the Sign-in Page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console.html)

[How Users Sign In to Your Account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_how-users-sign-in.html)

The sign-in endpoint follows this pattern:

> https://AWS-account-ID-or-alias.signin.aws.amazon.com/console

In the long term it make sense to setup an easy to read account alias, but you will bookmark this page anyway. :D